SSH connection takes long time to establish over NAT
I have the following problem. When I want to connect to my Centos Server over SSH using Putty/Winscp from outside the network using NAT it takes quite a long time. The connection established from inside the network happens immediately. I am using pfSense. The connection to other servers is also not a problem. There were attempts many attempts from the outside world to get in, so I changed the port number but the problem remains, therefore I assume the issue remains on my destination server.
Any suggestions on what to do on my Centos server to speed up and establish a connection faster  would be helpful.
There are no new accounts created,
no new firewall rules,
Nothing seems to be indicating the server was hacked.
Thank you

Depending on exactly how long "a long time" is, it could be the DNS lookup that sshd does by default for any new connection. If the remote IP space doesn't have reverse DNS with matching forward DNS or is on a slow connection/server, that could slow down the initial connection considerably.
You can disable this in your sshd configuration. See this other question for details: SSH reverse DNS lookup
The short version is that you can set UseDNS=no in your sshd configuration to disable the forward lookup part of it, but the main PTR lookup can only be disabled with the -u0 command line switch on sshd.

a long time is about 25 seconds to do authentification. The "interesting" thing is that the connection to all other servers behind the pfsense is created immediately. Everythig is set trough NAT. I dont use any revers proxys or DNSs anything else.

I disableed DNS lookups in PuTTY with Uncheck "Attempt GSSAPI authentication." This does speed up the established connection time.... Should I also change some ssh settings on my server in this case? and also, does this present a security risk?
